# When uploading files to SharePoint via Windows Explorer, is there a way to write into a log the errors encountered?

Tags: 2013, logging

The scenario is users will be manually uploading a lot of their files to SharePoint via Windows Explorer, and we need to be able to identify the files that failed to be uploaded (it may be due to long file path, unacceptable chars in the file name, etc). Since they'll be using Windows Explorer to upload to SharePoint, I don't think the errors encountered will be logged in the SharePoint logs. Hope you can provide some ideas how to log the failed files or maybe the errors are already being captured in a log but I just don't know what log it is?

Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint generate logs for uploading failures also. But sometimes it can give '*Unknown Error*' in the logs as well. We can generate our own log message but only if it is a Custom Component. If it is a OOTB library, we cannot. But we can define custom Error Pages, which can show data in a better way.

Hope it helps.